# Registry for odbcad32 on Window Server 2003 64-bit

Tags: windows-registry, odbc, windows-server-2003-r2

I used to use below registry to import some settings for setting up odbc on Windows Server 2003 32-bit. Now I want to do the same on a Windows Server 2003 64-bit for 32-bit odbc driver not the 64-bit one. Is there any way to modify the registry? Since this one will create entries for 64-bit odbc driver.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\MY_DB]
"Driver"="C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\SQLSRV32.dll"
"Server"="10.1.1.1"
"Database"="MY_DB"
"LastUser"="db_account"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC Data Sources]
"MY_DB"="SQL Server"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to configure 32 bit ODBC on 64 bit Windows then use:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBC.INI
```

ODBC setting visible to 32 bit applications will be stored here. If you create 32 bit installer then use simply `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI` and Windows will map it to `Wow6432Node` . More info about mapping registry to 32 bit apps on Win64 can be found here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305097